# Javascript library to align tab separated data (like elastictabstops)

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have some tab separated data, and want it to all line up nicely in columns with a fixed width font, so...

```
Head 1  Head2   Head 3
Item on is quite long   Item 2  Item 3
```

Becomes...

```
Head 1                  Head2   Head 3
Item on is quite long   Item 2  Item 3
```

I don't mind if spaces are used instead of tabs, and would most prefer a mix of the two, rather like elastic tabstops

Comment: I am homing there is a library for elastic tabstops, where I can feed it plain text, and it outputs elasticated tabulated output. I can't find a javascript implementation of elastic tabstops. If there is none, I would like to use a different library - there must have been many made over the decades, but I can't find a javascript library for aligning tab separated data into fixed width columns.

Comment: I didn't see one after a quick search, but it seems relatively straightforward to accomplish on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a function myself that follows loosely the format of elastic tabstops but without the complexity I did not require (my table is all one block and has equal columns for each row)

It works for my test case (and my actual use case) where I throw the first block at the function `align` and it returns the second block.

in CoffeeScript:

```
align = (d)->
    b = []
    l = []
    $.each d.split(/\n/), ->
        a = []
        $.each this.split(/(\t+|\s\s+)/), ->
            if this.match /\w/
                a.push this.toString()
                if l[a.length-1]? < this.length then l[a.length-1] = this.length
        b.push a

    pad = (txt, len)->
        while (txt.length<len)
            txt += " "
        txt

    o = "\n"
    $.each b, ->
        $.each this, (i)->
            o += pad this.toString(), l[i]
            o += "\t"
        o += "\n"
    o
```

Compiles to javascript:

```
var align;
align = function(d) {
  var b, l, o, pad;
  b = [];
  l = [];
  $.each(d.split(/\n/), function() {
    var a;
    a = [];
    $.each(this.split(/(\t+|\s\s+)/), function() {
      if (this.match(/\w/)) {
        a.push(this.toString());
        if ((l[a.length - 1] != null) < this.length) {
          return l[a.length - 1] = this.length;
        }
      }
    });
    return b.push(a);
  });
  pad = function(txt, len) {
    while (txt.length < len) {
      txt += " ";
    }
    return txt;
  };
  o = "\n";
  $.each(b, function() {
    $.each(this, function(i) {
      o += pad(this.toString(), l[i]);
      return o += "\t";
    });
    return o += "\n";
  });
  return o;
};
```